# How to connect from docker-compose to Host PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, docker, networking, localhost, docker-compose

I have a server with installed PostgreSQL. All my services work in containers (docker-compose). I want to use my Host PostgreSQL from containers. Buy I have the error:

```
  Unable to obtain Jdbc connection from DataSource (jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/shop-bd) for user 'shop-bd-user': Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  SQL State  : 08001
  Error Code : 0
  Message    : Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

  Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
  Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

My **docker-compose** is using **host network_mode**, like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  shop:  
    container_name: shop
    build: ./shop
    hostname: shop
    restart: always   
    ports:
      - 8084:8084
    network_mode: "host"
```

My **database connection UR**L is: **jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/shop-bd**

Comment: you are asking docker to port `8084:8084` and you don't say anything about port `5432`

Comment: @Krishna ```8084``` is port of this service. Other services can communicate with this one with ```http://localhost:8084```. But It does not work for host DB.

Comment: show how your config for `db` service looks like. It should have `5432:5432` under ports.

Comment: Which OS are you using docker on?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I develop on Windows

Answer (score 29, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#there-is-no-docker0-bridge-on-macos), from version 18.03 onwards, using `host.docker.internal` as DNS works for me, without specifying neither `--net=host` or `network_mode: "host"`

Comment: Cautionary note: using the --net=host, or network_mode: "host" will prevent your container from registering with Eureka and will break any kind of API gateway you've got unless they all run on the same network.

Comment: `This is for development purpose and will not work in a production environment outside of Docker Desktop for Mac`

Answer (score 6):

This would have worked if you were on linux OS. But this won't work on Mac or Windows. The thing is that when you use `--net=host`, you still are not on host network. That is the limitation of how docker for windows work

Instead of localhost you need to use `docker.for.win.localhost` as the host. This is a special DNS name which is available on Docker for Windows when you want to refer to the host localhost

Answer (score 4):

If you are mac user, use "host.docker.internal:5432" to connect to localhost Postgres, [docs](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/networking/).

Answer (score -3):

1) ensure that your postgresql instance is listening to all addresses and not only localhost.

In postgresql.conf set `listen_addresses` as follows:

```
listen_addresses='*'
```

2) you are trying to connect from your container to `localhost:5432` . That is NOT your host's IP address, but the address of your container's `loopback device`. You need to use your docker bridge IP address instead.

Comment: I use ```--net=host```, so I can use ```localhost```. I think, that the problem occurs because of Windows.

Comment: Yeah, you're right I missed that you are using host networking.